# How to share a port in Azure Service Fabric using Kestrel

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have multiple Service Fabric APIs. Both services are hosted in the same cluster using Kestrel. Currently each service is assigned to a specific port so they show up as

http://service1:123 and

http://service2:456

I would like to access the services using default port 80 for both. Is there a way to do this without having to use Azure API Management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, Kestrel doesn't support port sharing, but you can:

- run on IIS, inside [containers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/monub/2017/06/28/docker-blog-series-part-3-deploy-iis-based-applications-to-service-fabric-using-docker-containers/).
- use the [built in reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy)
- use a (containerized) reverse proxy like [Traefik](https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric)

Comment: could you please help in eloborating the build in reverse proxy. I have enabled reverse proxy with port 19081 how do i then map this to the service in port 123 to port 80. it there an option in the reverse proxy

Comment: the rp will make all http based services in your cluster accessible by name. E.g. `http(s)://<Cluster FQDN | internal IP>:Port/<ServiceInstanceName>/` So, if you have configured the (Azure) Load balancer to forward external port 80 to internal port 19081 your services will be accessible. The rp requires no port mappings, it interrogates the service endpoints and monitors for changes.

Comment: @kumar In addition to solutions in current answer you can also try to use [Placement Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#node-properties-and-placement-constraints) to make sure service replicas are always hosted on different nodes.

Comment: @OlegKarasik along you lines of suggestion. If I add another public IP to the existing loadbalancer and map that to the new service. that should work also. Right? So if I have 7 services running in the cluster then I will have 7 Public IP attached to the load balancer. Is there any down side to this approach?

Comment: @LoekD in your rp approach in the service manifest  in the endpoint section for the port do I put 19081? also what should the approach be if I need to use a combination of http and https with reverse proxy?

Comment: Running a service on a single node restricts the platform in its disaster recovery and rolling upgrade options. I recommend not doing that.  Leave the endpoint ports of the services empty, so they will all be assigned a unique port. Look into using Traefik instead of built-in RP, which allows customized rules.

Comment: @kumar using placement constraints doesn't mean restricting service to a single node. You can have custom placement constraints and simple have 5 nodes for service1 and 5 nodes for service2.